# DatePicker, FullCalendar and MySQL event dates end up being a day short

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

I am using a combination of DatePicker, FullCalendar and MySQL.

### DatePicker initialization

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#dp1').datepicker({
         autoclose: true,
         format: "yyyy-mm-dd"
     });
  });
</script>
```

### FullCalendar initialization

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      eventSources: [
        {
          url: 'data.php',
          type: 'POST'
        }
      ]
    })
  });
</script>
```

### FullCalendar event source 'data.php'

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calendar', 'user', 'pass');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM bookings");

$stmt->execute();

$return_array = array();
$event_array;

while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $event_array = array();

  $event_array['id'] = $row['id'];
  $event_array['title'] = $row['forename'] . " " . $row['surname'];
  $event_array['start'] = $row['start'];
  $event_array['end'] = $row['end'];
  $event_array['allDay'] = true;

  array_push($return_array, $event_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_array);
?>
```

My problem is that I can add an event to the MySQL database and the chosen dates are **2014-08-04** to **2014-08-08** but once added this appears on the calendar as **2014-08-04** to **2014-08-07**, 1 day short.

Here is the MySQL/PHP code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=calendar', 'user', 'pass');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO bookings (forename, surname, start, end) VALUES (:forename, :surname, STR_TO_DATE(:start,'%Y-%m-%d'), STR_TO_DATE(:end,'%Y-%m-%d'))");

$stmt->bindParam(':forename', $forename);
$stmt->bindParam(':surname', $surname);
$stmt->bindParam(':start', $start);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $end);

$forename = $_POST['inputForename'];
$surname = $_POST['inputSurname'];
$start = $_POST['dp1'];
$end = $_POST['dp2'];

$stmt->execute();

header("Location: /");
?>
```

I guess I am doing something wrong in the date conversion to MySQL but can't see what.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but thought I'd write this in the event someone stumbles upon it...

What you need to do is have your [nextDayThreshold](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/nextDayThreshold/) set in your initialisation:

`nextDayThreshold: "00:00:00"`

Then ensure that the dates you output have a time, I did this by appending `T23:59` to my dates, i.e. `2014-08-04` would become `2014-08-04T23:59`.

See these answers for more details:

[fullCalendar multi-day event spans 1 day too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941499/fullcalendar-multi-day-event-spans-1-day-too-short)

[fullCalendar multi-day event spans 1 day too short](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25941499/fullcalendar-multi-day-event-spans-1-day-too-short)